# How can I get the same element ids that the DeleteStaleTemplateCaches Task ends up with before the element has saved?

Tags: plugin-development, cache

I recently made [a plugin](https://github.com/supercool/Cache-Monster) that tries to keep the existing cache warm. It does this by listening to the `elements.onBeforeSaveElement` event, grabbing the id of that element and finding all the paths in the `craft_templatecaches` table then calls them with Guzzle.

The part I'm struggling with is the element id - when the event fires I just get the id of the element that first fired, in most cases the Entry. How do I ensure I get all of the correct `cacheIds` from the `craft_templatecacheelements` table? I only have the one element id, is there a way of ensuring I have all of the involved element ids?

I tried getting element ids from `craft_relations` by `sourceId` but still don't seem to be able to replicate the same kind of behaviour that the native cache clearing does. When I save an entry I get a bunch of element ids in the DeleteStaleTemplateCaches Task settings but can't find a way to get that same set of ids before the element saves.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental ...

Comment: Wouldn't you just be following similar logic as the [DeleteStaleTemplateCachesTask](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/tasks/DeleteStaleTemplateCachesTask.php) does in `getTotalSteps()` and `runStep()`?

Comment: Clearly I was missing something fundamental. /facepalm

Comment: lol - be sure and add an official answer when you get it sorted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not much of an answer but basically Brad was right - I just needed to replicate the logic that the [DeleteStaleTemplateCachesTask](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/tasks/DeleteStaleTemplateCachesTask.php) does in its `getTotalSteps()` and `runStep()` methods.

This allows you to work out exactly what caches will be just about to be deleted. I'm not going to post the code here as it is literally a copy/paste from the DeleteStaleTemplateCachesTask.